# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT. but i'm using PUT

Tags: php, laravel

> I'm trying to update my post table, yet it keeps giving me a method error, saying that I should be using `PUT` instead of `GET`.

The thing is I'm using `PUT`. I've tried to change the `@crsf` and change the `@method('PUT')` several times, putting a hidden input included. When I call `route:list`, it shows that I'm using the `PUT` method, yet it still gives me the same error. I have no idea what it could be, does anyone have any idea?

```
    <section id="index" class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
            <article class="new-post col-md-6 py-2">

                <header class="col-12 row d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <div class="add-header p-1">
                        <h2 class="m-2">Editar Post</h2>
                    </div>
                </header>

                <form method="POST" class="mt-5" action= "/edit_post/{id}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @method('PUT')
                    @csrf

                    <div class="add-photo form-group d-flex justify-content-center p-5">
                        <label for="file-input">
                            <img src="{{ url($post->imagem) }}" alt="imagem do post">
                        </label>
                        <input id="file-input" name="imagem" type="file">
                    </div>
```

```
    // rotinas pagina index
    Route::get('/index', 'PostsController@posts');

    // crud posts
    Route::get('/add_post', 'PostsController@adicionandoPost');
    Route::post('/add_post', 'PostsController@salvandoPost');
    Route::put('/edit_post/{id}', 'PostsController@alterarPost');
    Route::delete('/edit_post{id}', 'PostsController@deletarPost');

    //crud usuario
    Route::get('/profile/{id}', 'UserController@profile');
    Route::put('/profile/{id}', 'UserController@alterarUsuario');
    Route::delete('/index', 'UserController@deletarUsuario')->name('delete');

});
```

**PostsController:**

```
public function alterarPost($id, Request $request) {
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
```

**form:**

```
                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

                    <div class="add-photo form-group d-flex justify-content-center p-5">
                        <label for="file-input">
                            <img src="{{ url($post->imagem) }}" alt="imagem do post">
                        </label>
                        <input id="file-input" name="imagem" type="file">
                    </div>

                    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{$post->id}}">

                    <div class="add-input form-group mt-2">
                        <input class="col-12 p-1" name="descricao" type="text" placeholder="Descrição" value="{{ $post->descricao }}">
                    </div>

                    <div class="add-input form-group">
                        <input class="col-12 p-1" name="tags" type="text" placeholder="Tags" value="{{ $post->tags }}">
                    </div>

                    <div class="add_photo d-flex justify-content-end p-3">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger m-1" type="button">Cancelar</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-success m-1" type="submit">Publicar</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: You tried running `php artisan route:clear` yet?

Comment: yup! i've tried running route:clear and cache:clear, but still it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your **form** looks like.

```
 <form method="post" class="mt-5" action= "{{ route('editpost',['id'=>$post->id]) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ method_field('PUT') }}
        {{ csrf_field() }}
    </form>
```

your **web.php**

```
Route::put('/edit_post/{id}', 'PostsController@alterarPost')->name('editpost');
```

Comment: tried changing it, yet still it gives me the same error. say, is it possible that the error is happening in the index? because it only shows when i click on the link, maybe there is a conflict between the get from the index and the url?

Comment: `edit_post` is called `alterarPost` method of your `PostsController`. and in your question you're showing `alterarUsuario` code. try to change URL and debug it I think you misunderstood somewhere.

Comment: oh sorry, I pasted it wrong, but in the code it was correct.

Answer (score 0):

See your `Web.php` you have an error in your route Change this:

```
Route::delete('/edit_post{id}', 'PostsController@deletarPost');
```

To

```
Route::delete('/edit_post/{id}', 'PostsController@deletarPost');
```

You have forgot to add `/`

Comment: oh, thanks! it'd give me some trouble later, but the error is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

In your form change the enctype to be :

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

`Put` and `Patch` actions don't use the typical form-data of post.

Answer (score 0):

**Check your .htaccess file once it should have this line**

```
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS"
```